# proper JavaScript 'or' syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Im trying to check an input files extension with JavaScript, using:

```
if(extension != 'jpeg, JPEG, JPG, jpg'){}
```

I want the statement to read logically :'if variable extension doesn't equal jpeg, or JPEG, or..' and so on

but this doesn't work, how do I code this properly?

Comment: That's **Javascript**, not jQuery.

Comment: shrink down the check, use toLowerCase()!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `regex` you can do something like:

```
extension = extension.toLowerCase();
if(extension != 'jpeg' && extension != 'jpg')
```

This will also filter file extensions like `JpEg`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use regex for this, though? "If you don't want to use a hammer, you can bash that nail in with a rock."

Comment: Because well... almost no one likes regex :-"

Answer (score 1):

```
if(extension != 'jpeg'|| extension != 'JPEG' || extension != 'JPG' || extension !='jpg'){
    // would do the magic for you ;-)    
}
```

It's simple javascript not jquery!

Comment: That expression is always `true`. Use and instead of or.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little cleaner since you can define the array of acceptable extensions elsewhere.

```
if ($.inArray(extension.toLowerCase(), ["jpeg", "jpg"]) !== -1) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(extension != 'jpeg' ||  extension !=  'JPEG' || extension != 'JPG' extension != 'jpg'){}
```

Comment: That expression is always `true`. Use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression here will make your life easier:

```
if (!extension.match(/^jpe?g$/i)) {
    alert("Bad extension");
}
```